# Windows Phone - access HTML5/javascript game global variable in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, html, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8 solution with the HTML5 template. My game is in a game.js file and I have a script in the webbrowser's body tag implementing my game. The game works as it should.

However, I have some problems with the hardware back button in Windows Phones. It closes my application, and I have tried overriding it, but I need to detect when the user is actually playing or is already in the menu screen, so I can let the app decide whether to go back to the menu or close the app.

I am thinking about using a global variable in my javascript/HTML5 game:

```
    var IsPlaying = false
```

when the user clicks the start button on the main menu, IsPlaying becomes true.
When the user clicks the hardware back button, I want to evaluate the value of IsPlaying on my override method:

```
        protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        bool IsPlaying = //Get value from game
        if (IsPlaying == true)
        {
            Browser.Navigate(new Uri(MainUri, UriKind.Relative)); //Restarts the game, thus bringing the user to the main menu
            e.Cancel = true;  //Cancels the default behavior.
        }
    }
```

So my question is, how can I retrieve the value of IsPlaying from the game?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`WebBrowser.InvokeScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method to execute a Javascript function from your C# code and retrieve the return value. So you can just write a function in your Javascript to return the value of the `IsPlaying` variable, then retrieve the value on the C# side by using `InvokeScript`.